# SQL connection String LocalDB - Console - keyword not supported "Server"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

Working on a tool that queries an SQL Server Express LocalDB implementation, and I've tested the code to see that it works, but when I move the connection string from a hard coded string to one in an xml config file that I wrote, it gives the error below:

[image: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: "Server"]

For reference, here is a shot of the code, I used prevously for the function call:

[image: SQL Query Function Testing Code.]

and this is what I currently have in the XML Configuration File:

[image: config file]

If I change "Server" to "Data Provider" it also says that Data Provider is an unsupported keyword.

Looking through other questions, this is more than likely related to string formatting, or how I'm reading it in, but it does this regardless of single or double quotes.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to connect to - I always use https://www.connectionstrings.com/ to double check my connectionstring if I run into issues.

Comment: Definitely going to check that out real quick. Shouldn't be too bad, but it's just localdb and it worked with I hardcoded it..... odd.....

Comment: Your hard-coded string uses "Data Source" and your configuration string uses "Server."

Comment: Yes, and I found that the issue was that I was keeping quotes, and it was tripping up the connection string as when imported it added quotes to keep it a string when they were already there. Changed back to Data Source and removed the quotes and we're good.

Answer (score 0):

Change Server back to Data Source and remove the quotes from the XML file.